# Migrating to Storm 2.2.0, issues with Kafka offsets

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am migrating from Storm 0.9.x to Storm 2.2.0. Following a code for Kafka spout:

```
    KafkaTridentSpoutConfig.Builder kafkaSpoutConfigBuilder = KafkaTridentSpoutConfig.builder(bootstrapServers, topic);

kafkaSpoutConfigBuilder.setProp(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, fetchSizeBytes);
kafkaSpoutConfigBuilder.setProp(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, clientId);
kafkaSpoutConfigBuilder.setProp(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
kafkaSpoutConfigBuilder.setProp(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

return new KafkaTridentSpoutOpaque(kafkaSpoutConfigBuilder.build());
```

But everytime I restart Storm Local Cluster, messages are read from the beginning. If I check offsets directly in Kafka for the particular group, there is no lag. It's like offsets from Kafka are not read. Using Kafka 2.8, Storm 2.2.0. I didn't have this issue with Storm 0.9.X. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `clientId`? Did that group exist before you started this code? If not, then you've just created a new group, and seeked the group to the end of the topic, where there is no lag

Comment: ClientId is the group, just kept the old name we had when we use old Storm. The group didn't exist, but I've run the code several times and messages are polled from the beginning over and over again. I can always see a log like this at first: INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.SubscriptionState - [Consumer clientId=consumer-SOMENAME-5, groupId=SOMENAME] Seeking to EARLIEST offset of partition SOMETOPICNAME-0